# Configure Quarkus Kafka Stream in Runtime

Tags: java, quarkus, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Java, Quarkus and Kafka Stream and, looking the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-streams) I can not find a way to configure without *application.properties*. I would like to configure in runtime by code due to having my Kafka's credentials in a AWS secret, so I do not know the property  *quarkus.kafka-streams.sasl.jaas-config* in buildtime.

Is there a way to configure by code?